# Testing If Object Has Been DeSerialized Using A Flag In Constructors

Tags: c#

I want to see if anyone could point out some folly that I am not aware of for this Serializable object inspection. I have an object running inside a "plugin" type API which is serialized. My host "plugin" object is serialized by the API, and I am saving settings inside a wrapper object that contains my settings. This object is serializable so that the API will save and restore my state using its own storage mechanism, which allows me to pass out a serializable object that it will restore for me.

I need to be able to test upon de-serialization of my "plugin" whether my saved settings are at the defaults or have been de-serialized. (The API also uses some object caching and I will see many invocations of the getter and setter that handles this MySerializableSettings object, so I can't
successfully do any testing inside this property's get/set methods: it's too confusing in there.)

I am using a private field inside my serialized object, which sets a field to false in the instance initializer, and the constructors set it to true. Serialization does not invoke the constructors, so it seems to be that if the field is at "false" when I get a handle on it in my "plugin", then I know that the object has been de-serialized, and is not the default object constructed by my "plugin".

The code is below. Any comments?

```
[Serializable]
public class MySerializableSettings
{
    private bool atDefaults = false;


    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor supports serialization. AtDefaults becomes true.
    /// </summary>
    public MySerializableSettings() {
        atDefaults = true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A flag to test if this object has been de-serialized.
    /// This property defaults to false. All constructors set it to true.
    /// Therefore, if this property is false, this object was created
    /// without any constructor having been invoked (de-serialized).
    /// </summary>
    internal bool AtDefaults {
        get { return atDefaults; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Serialization does not invoke the constructors." How do you think you create an object without using a constructor?

Comment: @clcto The documentation states that constructors don't run. Unfortunately, I think the default constructor is running: I have now hit a breakpoint where my trick is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method marked with the [`[OnDeserializing]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) attribute. From the msdn:

> Use the OnDeserializingAttribute to set default values during
>   deserialization.

So your class could look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class MySerializableSettings
{
    private bool atDefaults = false;

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing( StreamingContext context )
    {
        atDefaults = true;
    }

    internal bool AtDefaults {
        get { return atDefaults; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah! I'm going to give this a try! Thanks for that: it looks like exactly what I am looking for. I will post results after a test shortly.

Comment: Well, this seems to be the correct answer. However, in my code, the method is not invoked. I do not have a definitive answer, but in a discussion board on the API I am running in, someone mentioned the same thing. So this API may be doing something that prevents this attribute from working. I have also now discovered that my trick is not reliably working either. I am going to find another approach to my overall need. ... Thanks!